# Using multi_sort in a 2D associated array to create a ranked list

Tags: php, arrays

The following code combines 3 arrays that are filled with urls and scores, if the url matches the scores are added together to create an new array. I'm now trying to create a ranked list in the combined array in descending order but I not quite sure how to do it

```
<?php




$combined = array(); 

foreach($bingArray as $key=>$value){ // for each bing item
if(isset($combined[$key]))
    $combined[$key] += $value['score']; // add the score if already exists in $combined
else
    $combined[$key] = $value['score']; // set initial score if new
}

// do the same for google
foreach($googleArray as $key=>$value){
if(isset($combined[$key]))
    $combined[$key] += $value['score'];
else
    $combined[$key] = $value['score'];
}

// do the same for bing
foreach($bingArray as $key=>$value){
if(isset($combined[$key]))
    $combined[$key] += $value['score'];
else
    $combined[$key] = $value['score'];
}


array_multisort($value['score'], SORT_DESC,$combined);

print_r($combined); // print results  
?>
```

The following is the output I'm currently getting

```
Warning: array_multisort() [function.array-multisort]: 
Argument #1 is an unknown sort flag in   /homepublic_html/agg_results.php on line   230
Array ( [time.com/time/] => 200 [time.gov/] => 297 [timeanddate.com/worldclock/] 
=> 294 [timeanddate.com/] => 194  [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time] => 289 
[worldtimezone.com/] => 190 [time100.time.com/]=> 188 
[time.gov/timezone.cgi?  Eastern/d/-5/java] 
=> 186    [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(magazine)] 
=> 275   [dictionary.reference.com/browse/time] => 182 [time.com/] 
=> 100 [time.com/time/magazine]
=> 96 [time.is/] => 95 [tycho.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/timer.pl] 
=> 94 [twitter.com/TIME]   => 93 [worldtimeserver.com/] => 92 )
```

Any help would be great guys and dolls

Answer (score 1):

[this ought to be a comment, but due to my status (reputation<50) I can only write posts ...]

I checked the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) again and found that for the sort task you are trying to perform the first argument of the function `array_multisort` needs to be an array with the same key as the actual array (`$combined`) you want sorted. The argument `$value` is not an array but was only a variable living in the scope of the previous `foreach` loops.

You should modify your code to something like:

```
$score=array();    
foreach($bingArray as $key=>$value){ // for each bing item
    if(!isset($score[$key])) { $score[$key]=0; }
    $score[$key] += $value['score'] // add the score to $score
    $combined[$key] = $value;       // place the whole associative array into $combined
    }
```

and then later on:

```
array_multisort($score, SORT_DESC, $combine);
```

Comment: I put this code in and it worked

    array_multisort($combined);
    $reverse = array_reverse($combined, true);
    print_r($reverse);

Answer (score 0):

I put this code in and it worked

```
array_multisort($combined);
$reverse = array_reverse($combined, true);
print_r($reverse);
```

Thanks for your help